# Custom Sort Complicated Strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, string, sorting, tokenize

I have a list of filenames conforming to the pattern: `s[num][alpha1][alpha2].ext`

I need to sort, first by the number, then by alpha1, then by alpha2.  The last two aren't alphabetical, however, but rather should reflect a custom ordering.

I've created two lists representing the ordering for alpha1 and alpha2, like so:

```
alpha1Order = ["Fizz", "Buzz", "Ipsum", "Dolor", "Lorem"]
alpha2Order = ["Sit", "Amet", "Test"]
```

What's the best way to proceed?  My first though was to tokenize (somehow) such that I split each filename into its component parts (s, num, alpha1, alpha2), then sort, but I wasn't quite sure how to perform such a complicated sort.  Using a key function seemed clunky, as this sort didn't seem to lend itself to a simple ordering.

Comment: Once tokenized, your data is perfectly orderable with a `key` function.

Comment: Could you point me to more information on how to use the `key` function to order by multiple attributes?  I wasn't sure how to order by one first, then deeper by the second, then deeper by the third.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once tokenized, your data is perfectly orderable with a `key` function. Just return the index of the `alpha1Order` and `alpha2Order` lists for the value. Replace them with dictionaries to make the lookup easier:

```
alpha1Order = {token: i for i, token in enumerate(alpha1Order)}
alpha2Order = {token: i for i, token in enumerate(alpha2Order)}

def keyfunction(filename):
    num, alpha1, alpha2 = tokenize(filename)
    return int(num), alpha1Order[alpha1], alpha2Order[alpha2]
```

This returns a tuple to sort on; Python will use the first value to sort on, ordering anything that has the same `int(num)` value by the second entry, using the 3rd to break any values tied  on the first 2 entries.

Comment: Thank you, Martijn.  I've almost solved this problem, but ran into further issues with the tokenization.  I've posted that as a separate question due to its complexity, and would like to solve both issues before I resolve.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120378/split-a-python-string-using-multiple-delimiters

Comment: That's a separate issue; this answer doesn't stand or fall with how you solve the tokenization.