# Split a Python String Using Multiple Delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, tokenize

I have a somewhat complex filename following the pattern `s[num][alpha1][alpha2].ext` that I'm trying to tokenize.  The lexicons from which alpha1 and alpha2 are drawn are contained in two lists.

I found the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998629/python-split-string-with-multiple-delimiters useful, but it didn't solve my problem.

Between `[num]` and `[alpha1]`, a number precedes a letter (a fairly easy regex), but between `[alpha1]` and `[alpha2]`, I'm splitting between two words.

Given the filename `s13LoremIpsum.ext`, for instance, I'd want `("s", "13", "Lorem", "Ipsum")`.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Note that in this particular case, `[alpha2]` is a single letter, but I'm interested in solutions for **both** this case and the general case where `[alpha1]` and `[alpha2]` are words of arbitrary length.  Note also that the general case could introduce ambiguity if there is more than one possible splitting by combining words from the respective lexicons, e.g.

```
alpha1 = ["a", "ab"]
alpha2 = ["bc", "c"]
# How will we split?
splitString == ("a", "bc")
# --OR--
splitString == ("ab", "c")
```

Solving this ambiguity is a secondary concern, however.

Comment: Do alpha1 and alpha2 always start with a capital letter? And do they ever have capital letters within? Is there ever an alpha3?

Comment: Are `alpha1` and `alpha2` to match pre-defined values? Your other question implies that they would.

Comment: In the specific case, both alpha1 and alpha2 are all-capital.  In the general case, any words in either could be any mix of capital and lowercase.

Comment: And yes, alpha1 and alpha2 are drawn from two lists containing predefined possible values for each.

Comment: In that case you'll need to do what thefourtheye is suggesting.

Answer (score 3):

```
alpha1, alpha2 = ["a", "ab", "Lorem"], ["bc", "c", "Ipsum"]
import re
pattern = re.compile("(s)(\\d+)("+"|".join(alpha1) + ")(" + "|".join(alpha2)+")")
data = "s13LoremIpsum.ext"
result = [pattern.match(data).group(i) for i in range(1, 5)]
print result
```

**Output**

```
['s', '13', 'Lorem', 'Ipsum']
```

The actual compiled pattern can be checked like this

```
print pattern.pattern
```

which prints

```
(s)(\d+)(a|ab|Lorem)(bc|c|Ipsum)
```

Comment: Awesome, that looks really good!  I ran into an issue here, however:
Let `alpha1, alpha2 = ["AB", "ABC"], ["C", "D"]`.  Now let `data = "s13ABCC.ext"`.  We output `['s', '13', 'AB', 'C']`.  Note that we get the right answer if alpha1 has the order of its items switched.  How could we fix this behavior?

Comment: @Walker If we have to manually split them, how would we do it? Shouldn't `CC` be part of `alpha2`?

Comment: I guess we're skirting the ambiguity I mentioned in my post, but in this example, the only word at the end that is contained in the alpha2 lexicon would be `C`, so alpha1 should then evaluate to `ABC`, rather then just `AB`.

Comment: @Walker Then include `ABC` in `alpha1` before `AB`. Problem solved :)